# How can I compare a string to an object key and get that key's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to do something relatively simple, I think anyways.

I need to compare the pathname of page with an object's kv pairs. For example:

```
if("pathname" === "key"){return value;}
```

That's pretty much it. I'm not sure how to do it in either regular Javascript or jQuery. Either are acceptable.

You can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lz430/2rhds1x3/

JavaScript:

```
var pageID = "/electrical-electronic-tape/c/864";
var pageList = [{
    "/electrical-electronic-tape/c/864": "ElectronicTape",
    "/industrial-tape/c/889": "IndustrialTape",
    "/sandblasting-tape/c/900": "SandblastingTape",
    "/Foam-Tape/c/875": "FoamTape",
    "/double-coated-d-c-dhesive-tape/c/872": "DCTape",
    "/Adhesive-Transfer-Tape/c/919": "ATTape",
    "/Reflective-Tape/c/884": "ReflectiveTape",
    "/custom-moulding": "CustomMoulding",
    "/request-a-quote": "RequestQuote"
}];
var label = pageID in pageList;
$('.el').html(label);
```

Comment: Just do: `pageList[pageID]` (well actually `pageList[0][pageID]`).  If it doesn't exist, it'll just be `undefined`.  Or, I guess you could do `pageList[pageID] || ''`.  Also Why is `pageList` an array of one object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your "pageList" should just be a plain object, not an object in an array:

```
var pageList = {
    "/electrical-electronic-tape/c/864": "ElectronicTape",
    "/industrial-tape/c/889": "IndustrialTape",
    "/sandblasting-tape/c/900": "SandblastingTape",
    "/Foam-Tape/c/875": "FoamTape",
    "/double-coated-d-c-dhesive-tape/c/872": "DCTape",
    "/Adhesive-Transfer-Tape/c/919": "ATTape",
    "/Reflective-Tape/c/884": "ReflectiveTape",
    "/custom-moulding": "CustomMoulding",
    "/request-a-quote": "RequestQuote"
};
```

Then you can set "label" to the value from the mapping:

```
var label = pageList[pageID] || "(not found)";
```

That last bit of the statement above will set the label to "(not found)" if the lookup fails, which may or may not be applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends kinda on the logic you want to implement. If you want to say "if object has the key, then do X, and if not, then do Y", then you handle that differently than "set label to the object's key's value if the key is there, or else set it to `undefined` or something else".

For the first case you do:

```
if (pageList.hasOwnProperty(pageID) ) {
  label =  pageList[pageID];
}
else {
  // do whatever, maybe some error?
}
```

For the second case, you can just say

```
 var label = pageList[pageID] || 'notFound';
```

As indicated by @Pointy, either get rid of the array or subsiture `pageList[0]` for `pageList` and `pageList[0][pageID]` for `pageList[pageID]` above, if you need to keep the array.